# Must permalinks always point to single post pages?

Tags: posts, archives, permalinks

Suppose that I have a blog with few posts per month, and no comments, and I don't want to show posts in single post pages, but always "in context" (say, together with the posts in its month - or perhaps a week?). To accomplish this, I'd need to use permalinks with fragment identifiers (#), among other things. I wonder if this is supported, or if someone can point me to some resource or discussion.

*Edited*: I posted in my own answer the details of my implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two hooks named `'pre_post_link'` and `'post_link'`. Their first argument – which you can change – is the permalink. So …

```
add_filter( 'pre_post_link', 'wpse_42406_change_permalink', 10, 2 );

function wpse_42406_change_permalink( $permalink, $post )
{
    // change the permalink, let it point to an archive etc.
    return $permalink;
}
```

… will change the output.

In your loop you probably use something like …

```
<li id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
```

Your permalink could then point to the archive page of your choice plus `#post-$post->ID`. For example:

```
http://example.com/2012/04/#post-42
```

Comment: Toscho - this would prove problematic for paginated archives though right?

Comment: Yes, you’d need to calculate the correct page … which is a moving target because new posts are added. So it is not exactly a permalink. :)

Comment: It's a weakness inherent in the request though really - any use of '#' assumes a month's worth of posts all fit inside one page. So the number of posts on each archive page would have to be set 'sufficiently' high. Leonbloy- a simple application of `pre_get_posts` should do the trick :).

Comment: With the above caveat +1 :).

Comment: Even the option `posts_per_page` can be changed (by a plugin) _after_ you fiddled out the permalink. :D Really, I wouldn’t do that.

Comment: Plug-ins could even undo your example :D. You'd just have to hook it really late. It's not fool-proof, but the other option is to have a non-permanent permalink. Or maybe interpret `2012/04/#post-42` and redirect it to the appropriate archive page with `#post-42`?

Comment: It may be easier to use just the plain old `/?p=123` and redirect on the fly.

Comment: Ok, I now stop adding +1 to every comment. Good discussion going on here, worth a blog post :).

Comment: Thanks for all the comments, perhaps I'll update the post later with my progress or findings.

Answer (score 0):

Just open your theme files and remove the a tags from the title.

Example:
In your index.php file if you had:

```
<h2>
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title(); ?>">
    <?php the_title(); ?></a>
</h2>
```

it would become:

```
<h2 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case some visitor find this info useful, I post my working implementation. It requires a little plugin.

In this implementation, the permalinks will show the monthly archive - but the url will still be "complete", i.e., include the post title - In this way, 1) I have more freedom if I wish to change this schema later, without breaking the permalinks, and  2) I have meaningful stats for my visits (I can know which individual posts was visited from my logs).

In the admin page I specify this permalinks structure :

```
/%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%  
eg: http://example.com/myblog/2012/01/sample_post
```

But the final permalink will be of the form:

```
http://example.com/myblog/2012/01/sample_post#post-234
```

The fragment identifier is added by the following hook in the plugin:

```
/* adds hash */
function hjg_change_permalink( $permalink, $post ) {
    //if(strpos($permalink,'#')) return $permalink;
    return $permalink . "#post-" . $post->ID;   
}

add_filter( 'post_link', 'hjg_change_permalink', 100, 2 );
```

I also hoooked the following in the plugin, so that the permalinks, despite looking as individual posts url, are interpreted as archives:

```
function hjg_parse_request( $wp ) {
   if(! isset($wp->query_vars)) return;
   if(! isset($wp->query_vars['year'])) return;
   $wp->query_vars['name']=''; // remove post name
}

add_action( 'parse_request', 'hjg_parse_request');
```

My theme is inherited from the standard `twenty-eleven`, which already ads a "post-NNN"  id to each post, in `content.php` :

```
   <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
```

if you are using other theme, you'd need to add or adapt this.

Remeber that, for this to work, your monthly archives should not be paged: you need to have a maximum number of posts per month, and set that value in the "posts-per-page" in the admin page. (I also tweaked the `index.php` file in my theme so that the front page shows a smaller number of posts).