# Add segment to URL in htaccess

Tags: permalinks, htaccess

I want to edit .WordPress .htaccess file, add a segment to URL in the following fashion:

Instead of:

```
http://www.example.com/mypost/
```

make it

```
http://www.example.com/coolstuff/mypost
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/42409/73)?

Comment: This is very interesting, @tosho, but difficult for me to understand. Could you provide "geek to English" translation, please? What does it do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to *Settings/Permalinks* and add the static string to to the permalink structure:

[image]

No need to touch the .htaccess.

### Update

To make WordPress sending a hash `#` for its post permalinks you have to filter `pre_post_link` to make the structure `'#%postname%'` and `post_link` to remove trailing slashes:

```
add_filter( 'pre_post_link', function( $permalink ){
    return '#%postname%';
});

add_filter( 'post_link', function( $permalink ){
    return rtrim( $permalink, '/' );
});
```

Be aware, you will [ruin your site](http://isolani.co.uk/blog/javascript/BreakingTheWebWithHashBangs) with those permalinks.

See also [Change the link URL in default RSS feeds](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/96602/change-the-link-url-in-default-rss-feeds)

Comment: Doesn't work in my case. I need #/ added, and wordpress wipes it clean

Comment: Hashes are not sent to the server; that’s a completely different question. And we have already answers for that on our site.

Comment: I read in a whole bunch of sites, including many stackexchange discussions, that you can escape a hash with a [NE], and it redirects just fine. The question I am asking, however, is "how can I add segment to wordpress URL using .htaccess, @toscho. I'm not asking about the hash, and I'm not asking about the settings/permalinks page.

Comment: You cannot use the .htaccess for that because the server will never see the `#` and anything that follows from a request.

Comment: This document says otherwise, @toscho: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/advanced.html (please scroll down to "Redirecting Anchors".

Comment: But the server doesn’t know if there is already an anchor in the browser request.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean, @toscho.

Comment: @Astoria See my update and the caveat.

Comment: Oh, I see how it works now, and I realize what I actually needed, in the first place. What I need is to REMOVE the hash, not to add it. Something like this: if there's a #/ before the rest of the page url, the browser should go to that url with the #/removed. Is that doable, @toscho?

Comment: @Astoria You can do that in JavaScript only. I am sure there are already solutions for that on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks, @toscho! And I appreciate your helping me to figure out the logic behind the proper behavior that I actually needed from the site.